# Typescript 4.0 adds export {} that interfere with RequireJS

Tags: typescript, requirejs

To compile typescript modules to be loaded by RequireJS I always used `module: "es2015"` (see below). This worked perfectly till ts 3.9 without the need of definition files whatsoever.

After upgrading to typescript 4.0.2 a line `export {};` is added at the end of each compiled file. This makes the load fail with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` error.
Same behavior with `module: esnext` or  `module: es2020`. The other kinds of module, even `module: "amd"`, give more important errors.

Besides adding an ugly post-compile step to remove the line or restructuring the entire application to get rid of RequireJS or opening an issue against typescript, what else could I do?

Thanks for your help!
mario

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "es2015",
        "noLib": false,
        "outDir": "../server/http/js",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "incremental": true,
        "tsBuildInfoFile": "./tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error"
    },
```

The RequireJS config is:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "..",
    paths: {
        "jquery":           "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min",  // Libraries
        . . .
        "refdata":          "js/refdata", // My modules
        . . .
    },
```

Comment: I assume there are, and have been, other `import` and `export` statements in the output unless you are writing AMD modules by hand.

Comment: Only for types. `import type {Tippy} from "tippy.js";
define(["jquery", "tippy", "jquery-ui", "jquery-layout"],
function($: JQueryStatic, tippy: Tippy) {` for example. And others has no import type at all

Comment: That is highly irregular. Basically, you are using `"module": "ES2015"` just to import types. You should just make your code work with AMD

Comment: Not to import types. To create a module that could be loaded by RequireJS.
Anyway, with an horrendous sed cycle I solved the problem UNTIL I have time to rewrite everything using ES6 modules or whatever.

Comment: Bang! Now I understand! The old code is written in a way that re-implement typescript "module: amd". Well, the refactorization will be blood and tears. Anyway, thanks Aluan for opening my eyes!

Comment: Yes, precisely. I should have been more explicit but I thought were already aware of that and had elected to manually write AMD modules, something I've seen done before. But it shouldn't be that hard to refactor. If you remove your type only imports and the `define` wrapper, then the auto-fix in an IDE will likely automate a lot of the refactoring.

Comment: Just to conclude. Refactoring and compilation went well. Now I'm suffering on the runtime RequireJS not finding few files to load. Anyway, this is another story. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I read your comments twice (they are shuffled, yay!) but still didn't figure out how to fix the problem. I have a similar case: I need to output files to be executed in the browser, i.e. plain javascript. UMD, CommonJS etc doesn't do the trick. ES2015 is the only module value which does the right thing but it adds this "export {}".

Comment: @ZitRo I don't fully understand. Perhaps ask a question so you can add details. This question is specific to the AMD module format.